# Can SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition use more memory (RAM) than Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard?

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2008-r2, ram

Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard can use only 32GB.

Windows Server has 128 GB RAM installed. Can SQL Server Services (SSIS/SSAS/SSRS/DB) use more ramm when OS or all of them are limited to 32GB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows won't recognize the excess memory and it won't be available for applications to use (including SQL Server). You would need to upgrade to either Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise or perhaps Windows Server 2012 Standard.

You can find information on the memory limits for different Windows editions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Yeah. Basically someone did not do the homework. GOod thing is - upgrading to 2012 standard fixes that, as the memory limit is then a LOT higher.